# Display 4D (3D + time) in XTK

Tags: xtk

I am trying to show a medical image known as SWI in XTK.  Single volume (timepoint) SWI for displays well.  However, we now acquire these images at multiple timepoints ending up with 4D images.  Would it be possible to extend XTK to 4D?  I can supply sample data.

Followup:  I'm working on a fork of XTK at https://github.com/bwagnerwork/X to implement this.

Followup 2014-10-24:  I've got a working version in the git location referenced above.

Comment: This is a very interesting use case for me as well. I can provide sample 4D DICOM data.